# Stream of example RTP packets

Tags: c++, packet, rtp

I am trying to tunnel RTP traffic through a user-defined protocol, and want to test this setup. Is there any C++ library, which I can use to generate example RTP packets and then tunnel them through my library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can see an example here: [RTPpacket](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/RTPpacket.html)

but is in java. 
Well this is the main page [streaming tcp/udp](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html)

Hope can be helpfull! 
Bye

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jRtpLib](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib). [Live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) is another open source RTP RTSP lib but would probably be harder to integrate. Both are free open source cross platform c++ libraries with "liberal" licences. AFAIR JRTPLIB focuses more on the RTP/RTCP side or at least it did when i last looked at it. It was fairly easy to get started. The one from live555 is more comprehensive featuring an event loop, many RTP payload formats, RTSP, etc. but is also more difficult to understand.